# Show all values in an array for a particular number in one column

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

How can I print all other numbers in an array, for a particular value in the first column?

Example: Lets say I have 4 columns, given as:

```
[1   1   1]
[1   1   2]
[1   2   1]
[1   2   2]
[2   1   1]
[2   1   2]
[2   2   1]
[2   2   2]
```

Is there a straight-forward way for me to extract the numbers for the second and third column, for each unique number in the first column?

I know I can sort the array by columns, find the unique values in each column, and find the indices of those unique values.  I think what I'd like is:

```
col1val = 1
col2vals = [[1], [1], [2], [2]]
col3vals = [[1], [2], [1], [2]]
```

(or something of the sort).

EDIT: 
  A big 'Thank you' to @Randrian for the suggestion that led me to this:

```
unique, indices = np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True)
print(a[indices[0]:indices[1],1])  # column 2
```

which gives:

```
[1 1 2 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use numpy you can use:

```
a = np.array([[1   1   1],
[1   1   2],
[1   2   1],
[1   2   2],
[2   1   1],
[2   1   2],
[2   2   1],
[2   2   2]])
```

and extract unique values with:

```
indices = np.unique(a[:,0])
```

What you exactly want to do the the unique numbers in the first column is not clear to me. You can use them as indices for the second and third column:

```
print(a[indices, 1])  # column 2
print(a[indices, 2])  # column 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all those columns are contained in a iterable object called `cols` I'd do it as follows.

```
def extract_values(cols, first_value):
    result = tuple()
    for col in cols:
        if col[0] == first_value:
            while len(result) < len(col) - 1:
                result += ([],)
            for idx, entry in enumerate(col[1:]):
                    result[idx].append(entry)
    return result
```

Then you could just do something like

```
col1val = 1
col2val, col3val = extract_values(cols, col1val)
```

This would also probably be pretty easy to alter to make it work for a different entry other than the 0th, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.